# what is this hidden Zugo Flash movie doing on my page?

Tags: flash, privacy, malware, spyware

I  found a strange thing hidden on my page:

```
  <div id="SiUnhdqlqHN9t7wB_tbstore_container" style="left: -2000px; top: -2000px; position: absolute;">
       <param name="movie" value="http://tbupdate.zugo.com/ztb/2.5/jsi/man/fc.swf"/>
   <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always"/>
```

EDIT: I see that it's there in Chrome too, not just IE, and I have all of the web-service search enhancements etc disabled in Advanced Settings.

EDIT:  I examined the markup on a PC not in the office, and the Zugo was not present. Possibly only the PC or browsers on my PC at the office are affected.

YET ANOTHER EDIT: This seems to be the StartNow search extension.  Wish I knew how it got installed on my PC at work.

I would be using this grid to track data that would be covered by HIPAA and need to know that the privacy is not being compromised.  There should be nothing "phoning home" in this grid or on this page. Really.

PROGRAMMING ASPECT OF THE QUESTION: If allowScriptAccess is set to "always" can this SWF see everything in the DOM? And if the ID changes, is there any way for me to "kill" it using javascript?

Comment: Does this have anything to do with programming? Might be better off on http://superuser.com/ or http://security.stackexchange.com/

Comment: At first I thought it was something installed by a Web UI library to keep track of usage, perhaps during a trial period. I've edited out that bit of the question. I will edit the question further to turn it into a programming question.

Comment: The original question probably could have been better served on superuser or one of the other stackexchange sites. Also, you may want to post the resolution as an answer to your question instead of an edit; the FAQ endorses that (but recommends that you also consider other answers for marking as accepted).